# Existing AWS CDK events rule throwing error AddTarget is not defined for IRule

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to add target to an existing event rule using aws cdk. but its throwing an error saying 'AddTarget' is not defined for IRule. I tried to cast IRule to Rule, still it didn't work for me.

```
 IRule myRule = Rule.FromEventRuleArn(this, ruleId, ruleArn);
        myRule.AddTarget(new LambdaFunction(myLambda, new LambdaFunctionProps
        {                
            Event = RuleTargetInput.FromObject(myEvent)
        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to add target to an existing event rule

That's not going to work. `AddTarget` needs to *modify* the rule resource.  But an `IRule` is [read-only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_external).  The `ISomething` "interface" types are bare-bones subsets of `Something` types, that permit read-only referencing of resources external to the CDK App.

> I tried to cast IRule to Rule, still it didn't work for me

That's not going to help.  `Rule` implements `IRule`, not the other way around.

Comment: thank you.  is there any other work around where I can add target to an existing rule using aws cdk?

Comment: @SJP.  (1) Create a new `Rule` that duplicates the conditions of the existing one. (2) Move the existing rule resource into the CDK app.  See the preview [cdk import](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v1-main/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cdk-import) command. (3) Use a Custom Resource to update the existing rule with the new Lambda ARN - possible, but a CDK anti-pattern.